# why my logout button can logout but can't switch the view

Tags: swift, button, swiftui, logout

I have already set a logout button. The function of that button is correct which can actually logout. But there is a problem: when I press the logout button, I **can not switch the page to the view I want**, which is `LoginsignupView`. I can't find amything wrong in my code.

I want to know how to make it correctly.

Here is the code about logout

```
import SwiftUI

struct MainView: View {
    @State private var selection = 0
    
    @ObservedObject private var httpClient = HTTPUser()
    @State var isin : Bool = true
    
  
    
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        
        
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            ZStack{
                TabView(selection: $selection){
                    profile1View()
                        .tag(0)
                        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                        .navigationBarHidden(true)
                    //List(self.httpClient.user,id: \.id){ user in
                    profile3()
                        .tag(1)
                        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                        .navigationBarHidden(true)
                    
                    ZStack{
                        Image("background")
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFill()
                            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                        
                        NavigationLink(
                            destination: LoginsignupView().navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                                .navigationBarHidden(true))
                        {
                            
                            Text("logout").foregroundColor(.white)
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                                .padding(.vertical)
                                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 100)
                                .background(
                                    
                                    LinearGradient(gradient: .init(colors: [Color("Color"),Color("Color1"),Color("Color2")]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing)
                                )
                        }
                    }
                    .tag(2)
                    .onAppear(perform: httpClient.Logout)
                    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                    .navigationBarHidden(true)
    
                }
                .zIndex(0)
                .onAppear{
                    UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = .white
                }
            }
        }
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            TabBarView(selection: $selection)
                .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
        
        Divider()
        
    }
}

struct MainView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MainView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you create a [mre]? No one can compile what you have included here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the intent is to push a `LoginSignupView` once "Logout" is pressed, then you need a [NavigationView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationview) somewhere in the view hierarchy. `NavigationLink` itself won't do much.

However, from your code it looks like you perform logout once the last tab is shown. In which case you might also want to bind your existing `NavigationLink` to a boolean property. For example your tab might look like this:

```
NavigationView {
.....
                  ZStack{
                        Image("background")
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFill()
                            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                        
                        NavigationLink(
                            destination: LoginsignupView().navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                                .navigationBarHidden(true), isActive:$showingLogout)
                        {
                            
                            Text("logout").foregroundColor(.white)
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                                .padding(.vertical)
                                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 100)
                                .background(
                                    
                                    LinearGradient(gradient: .init(colors: [Color("Color"),Color("Color1"),Color("Color2")]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing)
                                )
                        }
                    }
                    .tag(2)
                    .onAppear(perform: {
                             httpClient.Logout()
                             showingLogout = true
                    })
                    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                    .navigationBarHidden(true)
}
```